# How to disable MonoDevelop automatic update checks from command line?

Tags: command-line, monodevelop

I'm maintaining a lab of workstations, on which I've installed [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/).  How can I (via a shell script that runs when the user logs in) prevent MonoDevelop from checking for updates and notifying the user?  (In this situation, individual users do not have permission to install updates, so the notification is misleading.)

I found the corresponding settings in `~/.config/MonoDevelop-2.6/MonoDevelopProperties.xml`:

```
<Property key="MonoDevelop.Ide.AddinUpdater.CkeckForUpdates" value="False" />
<Property key="AppUpdater.CheckAutomatically" value="False" />
```

Is there a sanctioned way to modify these config values via the command line (as opposed to, say, doing a PERL regex replacement)?

Comment: Is there a *problem* with a regex replacement? I say, if it works (with no side effects), use it.

Comment: @DiogoRocha as mentioned, please avoid trivial edits. If you are interested in knowing an answer please consider adding a bounty.

Comment: @Bob: That's the problem — it's difficult to make complex edits without side effects using a regex.  In Mac OS X, for example, there's the `defaults` command line utility for making edits to Mac OS X's XML settings files — simple, and no risk (compared to regex) of obliterating other user settings.